# JButton Release Action

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I am trying to create an action on a `JButton` release and I am not sure how to accomplish this. I can make an action just fine when the button is pressed. When the button is pressed it will change the image to a red dot and when released it should change back to a default green dot.

My button press code is below if someone can point me in the direction on how to create an action when the button is released that would be most helpful. Thanks!

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    if (e.getSource() == change1) {

        p1a.setIcon(CLR); // THIS IS THE IMAGE WHEN BUTTON PRESSED
        // WOULD LIKE TO CHANGE BACK TO DEFAULT IMAGE HERE WHEN BUTTON IS RELEASED
    }
}
```

Comment: *"When the button is pressed it will change the image to a red dot and when released it should change back to a default green dot."* This can be entirely achieved within the `JButton`. See things like [`setPressedIcon(Icon)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#setPressedIcon-javax.swing.Icon-) ..

Comment: `JButton` already does this out of the box, why not make use of the available API?

Comment: I'm not looking for an Icon on the button itself to change I am looking for the image to change in a JPanel....same concept though

Comment: `I'm not looking for an Icon on the button itself to change I am looking for the image to change in a JPanel` - that is important information that should have been included with your original question. Be careful with the wording of your question as we can't guess what you really mean. The first two people to respond to your question thought you were talking about the icon of the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When the button is pressed it will change the image to a red dot and when released it should change back to a default green dot.

This can be entirely achieved within the `JButton`. See things like [`setPressedIcon(Icon)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#setPressedIcon-javax.swing.Icon-) ..

E.G.

[image] [image]

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.net.*;

public class ButtonIcons {

    ButtonIcons() throws MalformedURLException {
        ImageIcon redIcon = new ImageIcon(new URL(
                "https://i.stack.imgur.com/wCF8S.png"));
        ImageIcon grnIcon = new ImageIcon(new URL(
                "https://i.stack.imgur.com/T5uTa.png"));
        JButton button = new JButton("Click me!", grnIcon);
        button.setPressedIcon(redIcon);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, button);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable r = () -> {
            try {
                ButtonIcons o = new ButtonIcons();
            } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        };
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input and I will work it into my project. I gave an upvote however I need reputation of 15 for it to be show it said.

Answer (score 2):

> I'm not looking for an Icon on the button itself to change I am looking for the image to change in a JPanel....same concept though

Nice to have that information available ahead of time

One approach might be to attach a listener to the `ButtonModel` and monitor for it's state changes...

[image: Go][image: Stop]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.swing.ButtonModel;
import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private Icon normalIcon;
        private Icon pressedIcon;

        public TestPane() {
            setBorder(new EmptyBorder(16, 16, 16, 16));
            normalIcon = makeIcon(Color.GREEN);
            pressedIcon = makeIcon(Color.RED);

            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;

            JLabel label = new JLabel(normalIcon);
            JButton btn = new JButton("Pressy");

            add(btn, gbc);
            add(label, gbc);

            btn.getModel().addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
                    ButtonModel model = btn.getModel();
                    if (model.isArmed()) {
                        label.setIcon(pressedIcon);
                    } else {
                        label.setIcon(normalIcon);
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        protected Icon makeIcon(Color color) {
            BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(25, 25, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
            Graphics2D g2d = img.createGraphics();
            g2d.setColor(color);
            g2d.fillOval(0, 0, 25, 25);
            g2d.dispose();

            return new ImageIcon(img);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Both Answers will work in my project. Thanks!

Comment: (1+) This solution would also work if you activate the button using the keyboard.

Comment: @PilotinControl, `This is exactly what I was looking for` - don't forget to "accept" the answer by clicking on the checkmark so people know the problem has been solved.